# How to intuitively connect Linear Equation in two variables and the graph of them?

Tags: linear-algebra

I struggle with connecting graphs of linear equation with algebraic form like $x+y=p$.

How do I develop the intuition that it represents a line that is sloping down and passes through value $p$ on $y$-axis in $XY$ plane?

Comment: This question currently looks like it's more appropriate for Mathematics Stack Exchange. If it's about teaching graphs of linear equations, please edit to make that clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to write  it  as  y=-x+p  you see  that at x=0 y=p and x=p y=0  so for p>0 it goes down from (0,p) to (p,0)
if p<0 it goes down from (0,p)to (p,0)

Comment: sign of p is not that important because it does not affect the slope of line rather operation between "x" & "y" is important as it affects the slope of line...

Comment: so just look at the sing of x in the form y=... and you see the slope down, if the sign is negative.

Answer (score 0):

Write it as $y = p + (-1) x.$

- Along the $y$-axis, $x$ is $0,$ so the $y$-value is $p.$
- The $x$ is getting multiplied by $-1.$ So if you increase $x$ by some number, the $y$-value *decreases* by that number.
- In other words, each time you take one step to the right, you need to take one step down to stay on the line.